# C# method readability

Tags: c#, methods

In C# is there a way to combine methods into groups?
I have a class to communicate with a device. For each command I implemented, I made a method. This results in a few 100 methods. And for readability I would like to be able to combine these methods into sub groups so I could access them as this

```
DSP myDsp = new DSP(); 
uint32 serial = myDsp.MasterModule.GetSerialNr();  
string descriptor = myDsp.Eeprom.ReadDescriptor();
```

If I do this with a subclass then I lost all reference to the masterclass field and properties. For instance masterclass DSP holds a field address, if I make a subclass MasterModule then this class has no access to the address field.

Comment: `masterModule.GetSerialNr(myDsp);`? This would pass the dependency (DSP) to the MasterModule, so it has access to the members it exposes.

Comment: You can use regions to organize your code.

Comment: You should definitly refactor your code. 100 Methods seems far too much for a class. Maybe you can create classes that serve a specific purpose. This follows the single-responsibility-principle. If you even can make groups why not simply extract those members to independet classes at all?

Comment: don't use regions... its code smell.

Comment: This is off-topic on StackOverflow. You may want to try Programmers.SE or CodeReview.SE instead.

Comment: It's not entirely clear how you want to achieve readability. If you are worried about having a huge class file, then you use [regions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9a1ybwek.aspx) to group parts of the class together, and make these parts of the code collapsible in Visual Studio.

Comment: @Luaan when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info). Also, [at CR it would be blatantly off-topic](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Please abstain of recommending sites you're not familiar with

Comment: @gnat It feels to me like this falls entirely into the "Best practices and design pattern usage" category, which is common and desired on CR. Of course, not taken verbatim - Jakke would still have to write a question that fits CR style with his problem. Why do you think it would be off-topic?

Comment: @Luaan follow the link in my prior comment, it leads to their help/on-topic section. There is simple six-yes requirement which must be _fully_ satisfied for on-topic questions, it includes: "Is it actual code from a project rather than pseudo-code or example code?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use Façade design pattern to group the functionality.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing built-in, but the following workarounds are commonly used:

1. Prefix your method names, e.g. `EepromReadDescriptor`, so that IntelliSense puts them close together, and put them in [partial classes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488.aspx) to structure your source code.
2. The subclass approach works as well, but you need to pass a reference to the required information (such as the address) to the constructor of the "subclass".

Comment: Interfaces, inheritance, abstract classes, read-only properties, generics... there's *plenty* built in. Just get creative and use them as tools. C# is luxurious, enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

"This results in a few 100 methods" sounds to me like your class is doing too much so yes I agree you need to split it up. You'll most likely find there are certain functions that can be grouped (as you've mentioned) and that in reality you only need to pass in a few of the members of the main class for those functions to work. i.e. this data could be grouped into a separate class that could be passed into constructors.  Its impossible to say any more without looking at your code in more detail, but in my view a little careful thought and design would result in a better structure for your code.

Comment: i'm trying to write a device driver for an embedded device were making. So this thing can do tons of stuff but in an application i propably won't need all of it. But i'm implementing a driver now so i should make all the functionality available thats why i have this many methods that i would like to organize logically...  In analogy there is a camera i use sometimes. In C# i create 1 object uEye myCam = new uEye(); and then i have access to al the functionality like so myCam.Acquisition.Capture(); myCam.Device.GetInfo() etc... It's something like this i would like to create..

Comment: Ok so yes you have a driver but that driver can be made up of many classes.  i would be very wary of having 100s of methods in one class.  There will be logically separate functions that you can separate out. Without seeing your code though I cannot say any more.

Comment: " i propably won't need all of it. But i'm implementing a driver now so i should make all the functionality available" - I'd argue against this.  Ideally you should only really implement what you need to.  If you need any of the other requirements in the future then you should be able to easily add at that point. Remember YAGNI! https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren%27t_gonna_need_it - @JakkeFire

Answer (score 0):

The answers make the point that you should split your class, but perhaps that is not possible. Instead you can group the methods using several interfaces:

```
 // Methods grouped by interface
 public interface IMasterModule
 {
     uint32 GetSerialNr();
 }

 public interface IEprom
 {
     string ReadDescriptor();
 }

 // Now for your huge class
 public class DSP : IMasterModule, IEprom
 {
     // Properties which expose the groups
     public IMasterModule MasterModule { get { return this; } }
     public IEprom        Eprom        { get { return this; } }

     // --------------- IMasterModule -------------

     // Now your methods, which have access to the main class
     public uint32 GetSerialNr()
     {
         ...
     }

     // ----------------- IEprom -----------------

     public string ReadDescriptor()
     {
        ...
     }

 }
```

Visually separating the code into groups is important. 
You could use #region instead, but comments with hypens are more visible.

Now to use those groups:

```
   DSP myDsp = new DSP(); 

   uint32 serial = myDsp.MasterModule.GetSerialNr();  
   string descriptor = myDsp.Eeprom.ReadDescriptor();
```

Comment: For something like this, I'd probably use `partial` classes instead of regions. It can separate the different interfaces in a way that's easy to follow and deal with separately. You'll still have the (presumably huge) common interface, but getting rid of that needs a bit more refactoring and redesigning.